# ApolloClient: How to share queries between components?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

If ComponentA and ComponentB are both using this mutation:

```
const UPDATE_STATUS = gql'mutation updateStatus ($status: String) ...'
```

Should they share the same string from a common module, or should they both maintain their own copy of the string.

I am just trying to know if there is a best practice among the community regarding this.

Comment: share, import from *.graphql files, use fragments

Comment: So I organize queries/mutations in modules so I can share/import, and I use fragments to DRY things. Good.

Comment: just one query/mutation/fragment in one .graphql file - import what you need - look at [apollo-universal-starter-kit](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/tree/master/packages/client/src/modules/post/graphql)

Comment: Waouh! I will end up with many many files, especially for mutations ... ok

Comment: depends on requirements - groupped per domain/module - only 3 for `upload`, 1 in `contact`

Comment: OK, thanks. Your code (starter-kit) is helping me solve another issue. Thanks

Comment: It's not my code, just a suitable example

Comment: Sorry, I was just seeing what the Chat interface looks like, I did not type any message. It is ok, I got you 5/5.